# how to manage a minimap when using the Stage class?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm fairly new to Game development and to Libgdx as well. I'have looked around other similar topics in the forum but often I'm confused trying to understanding their content, therefore I decided to write down my problem here.

My problem is all about creating a minimap in the left bottom corner of the game screen showing the entire world with actors. I'd like to use the scene2d concept as much as possible.

For now I'm concentrating on the desktop version of the game.

I have a windows screen ... saying width = 800, height = 600

The top class of the game, MyOp0Game, is like this:

```
public class MyOp0Game extends Game {

   MyScreen0 my_screen_0;

   @Override
   public void create() {

      // allocate screen
      my_screen_0 = new MyScreen0(this);

      // set current screen
      setScreen(my_screen_0);
   }

   @Override
        public void render() {

            super.render();
        }   
}
```

The MyScreen0 class is like this:

```
public class MyScreen0 implements Screen{

    protected final Stage stage0;
    protected final MyOp0Game game;
    protected final MyActor0 actor0;
    protected final MyActor0 actor1;

    public MyScreen0(MyOp0Game game) {

        // link screen to game
       this.game = game;

        // allocate stage; viewport size maps screen size
        this.stage0 = new Stage( Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true );

        // allocate actor0 and add to stage
        this.actor0 = new MyActor0();
        this.actor0.setPosition(0, 0);
        this.stage0.addActor(this.actor0);

        // allocate actor1 and add to stage, actor1 is placed next to actor0
        this.actor1 = new MyActor0();
        this.actor1.setPosition(1000, 0);
        this.stage0.addActor(this.actor1);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        // the following code clears the screen with the given RGB color (green)
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0f, 1f, 0f, 1f );
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );   

        // translate stage camera to go from actor0 to actor1
        //this.stage0.getCamera().translate(1, 0, 0);

        // draw stage -> draw actors
        this.stage0.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
   // not required as no abstract screen for now
   //super.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
   this.stage0.dispose();
    }

}
```

Finally the MyActor0 class is like this :

```
public class MyActor0 extends Actor {

   SpriteBatch batch;
   Texture texture;

   public MyActor0() {   

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
   }

        public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float alpha){

                batch.draw(texture,this.getX(),this.getY());
        }
}
```

The stage viewport is of the same size as the window screen.
The actor texture is smaller than the viewport and therefore the first actor is visible and the second actor is not visible as it is next to the viewport.

I would like to insert in the bottom left a minimap showing the two actors (or equivalent markers).

I've tried several options but it never works, using two cameras and switching between them, two stages?

I think one fundamental question I have is : does the viewport always fills the windows screen?

Comment: Is your game top down? If it is you could somehow use a second cam and render the same things and use the cameras zoom. Just an idea. I don't realy know how to implement it actually but i wanted to give you an idea which may helps :P

Comment: thanks for the idea. yes it is top down. I've already tried something with two cameras but I'm not familiar enough to get a valid result. I've got another advice using another actor that render the minimap. I'll try it.

Comment: So you use a Group of actors or only 1 Actor? Should it always show the whole map or only a part of it?

Comment: Hello, I finally manage to do it using a new "minimap" that is another actor of the same stage. This "minimap" actor lists all the other actors from the stage, gets their position and translate them in the minimap. Then when the stage draw, it draws all the actors, including the minimap. I'll copy paste the code later on.

Comment: To answer your question, the minimap shows the entire world for now. I'm not sure about group of actors, but I guess the minimap should show everything existing in the real world. I can imagine that when created, an actor is automatically declared at the "minimap" actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the first prototype of the minimap, it will be enough for the first step of the game dev.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "my-op0-game";
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.width = MyOp0Game.MY_APP_WINDOW_WIDTH;
        cfg.height = MyOp0Game.MY_APP_WINDOW_HEIGHT;

        new LwjglApplication(new MyOp0Game(), cfg);
    }
}


public class MyOp0Game extends Game {

    public static int MY_APP_WINDOW_WIDTH = 512;
    public static int MY_APP_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 512;
    public static int MY_WORLD_WIDTH = 2048;
    public static int MY_WORLD_HEIGHT = 2048;
    public static int MY_MINIMAP_WIDTH = 256;
    public static int MY_MINIMAP_HEIGHT = 256;
    public static int MY_MINIMAP_SCALE_FACTOR = MY_WORLD_WIDTH / MY_MINIMAP_WIDTH;
    public static int MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_X = MY_APP_WINDOW_WIDTH/2;
    public static int MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_Y = MY_APP_WINDOW_HEIGHT/2;
    public static final String LOG = "MyOp0Game";

    MyScreen0 my_screen_0;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        // allocate screen
        my_screen_0 = new MyScreen0(this);

        // set current screen
        setScreen(my_screen_0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
    }   
}

public class MyScreen0 implements Screen{

    protected final Stage stage0;
    protected final MyOp0Game game;
    protected final MyActor0 actor0_0;
    protected final MyActor0 actor0_1;
    protected final MyActor1 actor1_0;


    public MyScreen0(MyOp0Game game) {

        // link screen to game
        this.game = game;

        // allocate stage; viewport size maps game window size
        this.stage0 = new Stage( Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true );

        // allocate actor0_0 and add to stage
        this.actor0_0 = new MyActor0();
        this.actor0_0.setPosition(0, 0);
        this.stage0.addActor(this.actor0_0);

        // allocate actor0_1 and add to stage, actor1 is placed next to actor0
        this.actor0_1 = new MyActor0();
        this.actor0_1.setPosition(512, 256);
        this.stage0.addActor(this.actor0_1);

        // allocate actor1_0 and add to stage
        this.actor1_0 = new MyActor1();
        this.actor1_0.setPosition(0, MyOp0Game.MY_APP_WINDOW_HEIGHT - MyOp0Game.MY_MINIMAP_HEIGHT);
        this.stage0.addActor(this.actor1_0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        int lvTranslateX = 0;
        int lvTranslateY = 0;

        // the following code clears the screen with the given RGB color (green)
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0f, 1f, 0f, 1f );
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); 

        /* check if mouse pressed */
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched())
        {
            //Gdx.app.log( MyOp0Game.LOG, " mouse X = "+ Gdx.input.getX() +
            //                          " Camera.x = " + this.stage0.getCamera().position.x +
            //                          " mouse Y = "+ (MyOp0Game.MY_APP_WINDOW_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY()) +
            //                          " Camera.y = " + this.stage0.getCamera().position.y);

            if (Gdx.input.getX() >= MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_X)
            {
                if (this.stage0.getCamera().position.x - MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_X < MyOp0Game.MY_WORLD_WIDTH - MyOp0Game.MY_APP_WINDOW_WIDTH)
                    lvTranslateX = 3;
            }
            else if (Gdx.input.getX() < MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_X)
            {
                if (this.stage0.getCamera().position.x - MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_X > 0)
                    lvTranslateX = -3;
            }

            if (MyOp0Game.MY_APP_WINDOW_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() >= MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_Y)
            {
                if (this.stage0.getCamera().position.y - MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_Y < MyOp0Game.MY_WORLD_HEIGHT - MyOp0Game.MY_APP_WINDOW_HEIGHT)
                    lvTranslateY = 3;
            }
            else if (MyOp0Game.MY_APP_WINDOW_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() < MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_Y)
            {
                if (this.stage0.getCamera().position.y - MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_Y > 0)
                    lvTranslateY = -3;
            }

            if (lvTranslateX != 0 || lvTranslateY != 0)
            {
                // translate stage camera to go from actor0 to actor1
                this.stage0.getCamera().translate(lvTranslateX, lvTranslateY, 0);

                // update actor1_0 (minimap) location to move with camera 
                this.actor1_0.translate(lvTranslateX,lvTranslateY);
            }
        };

        // draw stage -> draw actors
        this.stage0.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // not required as no abstract screen for now
        //super.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        this.stage0.dispose();
    }

}

public class MyActor0 extends Actor {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    public Texture texture;

    public MyActor0() { 
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx_256_256.png"));
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float alpha){
        batch.draw(texture,this.getX(),this.getY());
    }
}

public class MyActor1 extends Actor {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture texture;
    Texture blackMarkerTexture;
    Texture yelloCameraMinimapTexture;

    public MyActor1() {
        this.batch = new SpriteBatch();
        this.texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/blueBg_256_256.png"));
        this.blackMarkerTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/blackMarker_32_32.png"));
        this.yelloCameraMinimapTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/yelloCameraMinimap_64_64.png"));
        this.setName("minimap");

    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float alpha){

        // draw actor
        batch.draw(texture,this.getX(),this.getY());

        // draw game window in minimap
        batch.draw( this.yelloCameraMinimapTexture, 
                    this.getX() + (this.getStage().getCamera().position.x - MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_X)/MyOp0Game.MY_MINIMAP_SCALE_FACTOR, 
                    this.getY() + (this.getStage().getCamera().position.y - MyOp0Game.MY_ORIGINAL_CAMERA_POSITION_Y)/MyOp0Game.MY_MINIMAP_SCALE_FACTOR);

        // retrieve actors from stage
        Array<Actor> lvActorArray = this.getStage().getActors();
        for ( int lvIdx = 0; lvIdx < lvActorArray.size; lvIdx++ )
        {
            Actor lvActor = lvActorArray.get(lvIdx);
            if (lvActor.getName() != "minimap")
            {
                batch.draw( this.blackMarkerTexture, 
                            this.getX() + (lvActor.getX()/MyOp0Game.MY_MINIMAP_SCALE_FACTOR),
                            this.getY() + (lvActor.getY()/MyOp0Game.MY_MINIMAP_SCALE_FACTOR));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, I've posted the minimap prototype just above.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your comment but i could not find a Minimap Actor in the libgdx documentations. But i found this link, which may help you out: [Minimap](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Minimap). Tell me if this works (: